# Search unspecific term with specific answer

Tags: search, neo4j, full-text-search

I am building a database in Neo4J. I am trying to build a match query within the fulltext search. The search query has to be quite robust as it will take queries from users which are not familiar with the search term and return the node which best matches the term. I am aware of a few ways of doing this, but all require that the search term is fuzzied and not the return term. My current rules rely on contains / does not contain and loops, without building a new database, is there a way to fuzzy the search term so that essentially the nodes will search through the term provided and not the other way round?

I am aware that this may not make sense. It is only my 3rd day on Neo4J. Please let me know if you need any more clarification.

Edit: I figure that I can combine the does/does not contain search terms and fuzzy the search term, by increasing the does contain score and decreasing the does not contain score.

Comment: is there a way to fuzzy the search term so that essentially the nodes will search through the term provided and not the other way round? -> What does this mean?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I would like to search for items that my search term does not contain. For example, if searching for wxz, I would like to get a value back because my term does not contain y. I would also like the values that can be searched to be non-specific and undefined. The values that the term should not contain will be defined